# Why are convolutions so widely used in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution

Functional Analysis has never been particularly intuitive to me, but in recent years I'm starting to see how it aids Fourier Analysis, Operator Theory and PDEs, but for the life of me I don't get the fixation on the convolution operation. I know it has some applications in engineering but it dates back to the time of Laplace. How is it used in mathematics?

One example I can think of is if you have a family of good kernels/mollifiers $D_n$, $f\in L^p$ then $D_n * f$ are smooth and converge to $f$.

Comment: Because the Fourier transform maps convolutions into pointwise multiplication.

Comment: Why is this a useful property?

Comment: It is easier to manipulate multiplications of objects than convolutions.

Comment: But why do we care about convolutions? What do they allow us to do?

Comment: For example, they arise naturally in linear time invariant systems in control theory.

Comment: I'm looking for a general reason why they come up in functional analysis, if it exists. When I crack open a book on functional analysis, they spend a lot of time treating the convolution. I'm wondering if there is a general reason that they are used. Something akin to the example I gave. I.e., do they arise naturally in the theory?

Comment: "A book"? You make it sound like this is common. What books  would those be? I regularly teach functional analysis classes and I never mention convolution. Many of the classic books in the topic (Rudin, Conway, Royden, Brezis, among others) barely mention it, if at all. If the book is about harmonic analysis then yes, it will probably be mentioned often.

Comment: I'm referring to Stein and Shakarchi for instance. I've take courses in functional analysis and the convolution is usually mentioned and used in proofs, for instance, "good kernels" and general properties about it are taught. I was just wondering is there a reason they arise naturally?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's no "fixation" whatsoever. No more than there is a "fixation" with addition. Or with numbers. Or with vector spaces. Actually way way less, as convolution does not feature prominently.

In any case, convolution appears very naturally in lots of contexts. Off the top of my head, and with the caveat that I don't know/use/see convolution much:

- in Probability, the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables is the convolution of the distributions;
- when you multiply two polynomials, the coefficients of the products are obtained as the convolution of the coefficients;
- in Group Theory, $\ell^1(G)$ is made naturally an algebra with convolution as the product. "Natural" because the canonical basis satisfies $e_{gh}=e_g*e_h$;
- as mentioned by copper.hat, the Fourier transform takes convolution to pointwise product;
- as mentioned in the question, convolution allows one to show that $C^\infty$ functions  with compact support are dense in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Nice answer, adding to the product of polynomials one has the fact that the Cauchy product of two series can be understood as a convolution.